# Keycloak adding new authenticator

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'd like to add a new auth method in keycloak. To be precise - I'd like the keycloak to ask external API for some specific value. I have read about flows in keycloak but they seem to be poorly documented and I have a feeling that it is not very intuitive.

During login I would like the keycloak to send request to external API and if and only if when specific value is returned allow the user to login. For example I could override some login method and add a few lines of code doing what I want.

Which method in which class is responsible for login?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple things you need to do to achieve that. I will go over them:

1. Implement Authenticator and AuthenticatorFactory interfaces.
2. Copy an existing Authentication Flow
3. Bind flow

> I assume you know how to write and deploy a keycloak extension.

### 1. Implement Authenticator and AuthenticatorFactory interfaces.

The specific interfaces are those:

```java
org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticatorFactory
org.keycloak.authentication.Authenticator
```

A sample implementation:

```java
org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordFormFactory
org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm
```

If you want to externalize your config (So you can add username/password etc. for external api), override `getConfigProperties()` method in `AuthenticatorFactory`

### 2. Copy an existing Authentication Flow.

1. Login keycloak with admin credentials.
2. Create a new realm (or use if you have one)
3. Go to Authentication tab on left.
4. Copy browser login flow
   [image: copy flow]
5. Add your flows/executions (Your implementation of Authenticator/Factory will be listed under executions)
   You can move them up or down. Make them required or alternative etc.
   [image: add execution]
6. If you override config list it will be shown next to your execution
   [image]
   [image]

### 3. Bind flow.

Bind your flow in the second tab of Authentication page.
[image]

Comment: Can i use just `AbstractDirectGrantAuthenticator` instead of these two classes?

Comment: As long as it implements authenticator and authenticatorfactory you can use any class.

Comment: Does anyone have a sample or tutorial for this? I was trying to look through the official doc but it is kinda super bloat. I've never use java before but I just need this one and only component for my keycloak server.

Comment: There are great repositories on github for keycloak extensions. Such as: https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-extension-playground/