# How integrate Keycloak with external system which use rest to authenticate user

Tags: java, rest, authentication, keycloak

I'm trying to integrate my web app with keycloak where the user will login through external system as following :

- user will login to external web app
- user will click link in the external web app which will redirect it to
  my system without the need to login again .

the external web app only provided a rest call to authenticate the users so
is it possible to configure keycloak to call the rest point and do the authenticatication ?

Comment: yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800071/keycloak-adding-new-authenticator/67808514#67808514

Comment: @Ghokun thank you .... another question will it be possible to do it without showing the login page?so the user will be redirect to the new website without going through the login page

Comment: Not exactly the same but `org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.CookieAuthenticator` works like this. Check its `authenticate` method.