# Implementation of custom authentication in keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak

I'm trying to implement custom auth flow in Keycloak. It should work similar to username&password flow (POST /openid-connect/token with params 'username'+'password'+'grant_type=password' -> response with access_token & refresh_token) but instead of username and password it will receive another fields (e.g. fieldA, filedB and hash)

I wrote an implementation of

```
org.keycloak.authentication.Authenticator
```

that does this auth, but I can't figure out what should I do next. How can I make keycloak validate user using this flow?

Answer (score 4):

So If I understand you correctly: U have a custom implementation of the Authenticator interface, to register it in keyckoak you also need AuthenticatorFactory - implementation and add the path to it into the config file with the name: org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticatorFactory. So you should have something like:

```
    public class CustomAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
    
    
    @Override
    public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        //todo make your auth validation check logic
        String username = "admin";
        UserModel user = context.getSession().users().getUserByUsername(username, context.getRealm());
        context.setUser(user);
        context.success(); // With context.success(), or failing with an error, you can manage your custom validation
    }
}


public class CustomAuthenticatorFactory implements AuthenticatorFactory {
    
    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "custom-sso";
    
    private static CustomAuthenticator SINGLETON = new CustomAuthenticator();

    @Override
    public String getDisplayType() {
        return "custom sso";
    }

    @Override
    public AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement[] getRequirementChoices() {
        return REQUIREMENT_CHOICES;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Authenticator create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return SINGLETON;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }
}
```

And also in file with path: src\main\resources\META-`INF\services\org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticatorFactory`
need to add a path to the factory class.

After all these changes, you should be able to change your authentication flow from keyclaok admin page.

P.S. you cant change existed `Browser` flow, but you can copy it, change the copy and then bind the browser flow to your custom.

P.S.S.

I found almost the same question: [Keycloak adding new authenticator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800071/keycloak-adding-new-authenticator)

But with a better-described answer :-)

Comment: Why  CustomAuthenticator  singleton?