# Customize Keycloak 22 login

Tags: keycloak

I need to modify the login flow of Keycloak to do the following:

- If the user exists continue with the flow, else go to the next step
- If the user does not exists, make a request to another API to validate credentials
- If the credentials are valid in the other API, create a new user with attributes and password, else, continue with the flow

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After retrying for several days and asking for a new option in the question above, i revisit one of my previous ideas and this one worked:

**1. Create a small project with IntelliJ with this dependencies and files:**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

src/main/java/com.example/CustomPasswordAuthenticator

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowContext;
import org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm;
import org.keycloak.credential.PasswordCredentialProvider;
import org.keycloak.models.UserModel;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class CustomPasswordAuthenticator extends UsernamePasswordForm {

    @Override
    public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();
        String username = formData.getFirst("username");
        String password = formData.getFirst("password");
        UserModel user = context.getSession().users().getUserByUsername(context.getRealm(), username);
        // If user does not exits, try to create with external API credentials
        if (user == null) {
            try {
                String responseString = externalAuth(username, password);
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                JsonNode response = objectMapper.readTree(responseString);
                user = context.getSession().users().addUser(context.getRealm(), username);
                user.setEnabled(true);
                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setFirstName(response.get("firstName").asText());
                user.setLastName(response.get("lastName").asText());
                user.setSingleAttribute("externalId", response.get("customerId").asText());
                PasswordCredentialProvider passwordCredentialProvider = new PasswordCredentialProvider(context.getSession());
                passwordCredentialProvider.createCredential(context.getRealm(), user, password);
            } catch (Exception e){
                logger.error("Failed to authenticate user with External API ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Continue with the original login flow
        super.action(context);

    }

    public static String externalAuth(String username, String password) throws IOException {
        String urlWithParams = "https://{external-api-address}?email=" + username + "&password=" + password;
        URL url = new URL(urlWithParams);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "accessToken");
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

src/main/java/com.example/CustomPasswordAuthenticatorFactory

```
import org.keycloak.Config;
import org.keycloak.authentication.Authenticator;
import org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticatorFactory;
import org.keycloak.authentication.ConfigurableAuthenticatorFactory;
import org.keycloak.models.AuthenticationExecutionModel;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSessionFactory;
import org.keycloak.provider.ProviderConfigProperty;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomPasswordAuthenticatorFactory implements AuthenticatorFactory, ConfigurableAuthenticatorFactory {

    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "custom-authenticator";
    private static final CustomPasswordAuthenticator SINGLETON = new CustomPasswordAuthenticator();

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public Authenticator create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return SINGLETON;
    }

    private static AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement[] REQUIREMENT_CHOICES = {
            AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement.REQUIRED,
            AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement.ALTERNATIVE,
            AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement.DISABLED
    };
    @Override
    public AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement[] getRequirementChoices() {
        return REQUIREMENT_CHOICES;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserSetupAllowed() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConfigurable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
        return configProperties;
    }

    private static final List<ProviderConfigProperty> configProperties = new ArrayList<ProviderConfigProperty>();

    static {
        ProviderConfigProperty property;
        property = new ProviderConfigProperty();
        property.setName("cookie.max.age");
        property.setLabel("Cookie Max Age");
        property.setType(ProviderConfigProperty.STRING_TYPE);
        property.setHelpText("Max age in seconds of the custom_auth.");
        configProperties.add(property);
    }


    @Override
    public String getHelpText() {
        return "Description of the created authenticator.";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayType() {
        return "Custom Authentication Login";
    }

    @Override
    public String getReferenceCategory() {
        return "Custom Authentication Login";
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

}
```

/src/main/resources/META-INF.services/com.example.AuthenticatorFactory

```
org.keycloak.taxit.authenticator.CustomPasswordAuthenticatorFactory
```

**2. Package your project in a jar file.**

**3. Copy into the keycloak-folder/providers folder**

**4. Run the keycloak-folder/bin/kc.bat build command (windows)**

**5. Start the app  with kc.bat start-dev command**

**6. Go to the Keycloak Admin Console -> Authentication -> custom-flow -> Add Step -> Your Custom Authenticator**

**7. Finally, if you want to override the browser flow for example, go to Action -> Bind Flow**

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to implement a custom authentication flow.
You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75354307/implementation-of-custom-authentication-in-keycloak).