# Custom authentication in keycloak with custom list of roles

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak

I have implemented a custom Authenticator, similar to the one discussed in this StackOverflow post:
[Custom authenticator example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75354307/implementation-of-custom-authentication-in-keycloak/75360092?noredirect=1#comment136097979_75360092)

Now, I have a requirement to dynamically modify the list of roles for a user depending on their authentication method. Specifically, when a user authenticates using the user/password form, they should retain their existing roles. However, if they authenticate using a custom Authenticator, I need to trim their list of roles for the current session.

My keycloak version: `15.0.2`

Here's a snippet of my custom authentication logic:

```
UserModel existingUser = getExistingUser(userName, realmId);
if (existingUser != null) {
    context.setUser(existingUser);
    context.success();
} else {
    context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.UNKNOWN_USER);
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that `UserModel` roles are immutable, and while I can delete role mappings for the user, this action affects their roles in the database, not just for the current session:

```
// getRoleMappings - deprecated, I put it just as an example;
for (RoleModel r : user.getRoleMappings()) {
    user.deleteRoleMapping(r);
}
```